# What would be the domain of an integral of a function (that is unknown) that is on a closed interval?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I came upon this problem while doing my summer hw.

The function f(t) has domain [-2,3] on which it is continuous.

If h(x) = $\int_{-2}^{5x+2} f(t)dt$, then what would be the domain of h(x)?

What I already figured out is that h(x) cannot be outside the boundaries that f(t) already set by the original f(t). I also cannot use the fundamental theorem of calculus because I do not know the specific function.

Comment: You cannot integrate $f$ near $-2$ as it is undefined there.  My guess is that there is a typo in the question (either in the interval $[2,3]$ or in the integral).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f(t)$ is continuous on $[-2,3]$, then it is also integrable on $[-2,3]$. That means that your upper limit of integration needs to within the interval $[-2,3]$, in other words, you need,

$$-2 \leq 5x+2 \leq 3.$$

Solving this inequality yields,

$$\frac{-4}{5} \leq x \leq \frac{1}{5}$$

Thus, the domain of $h$ is $[\frac{-4}{5}, \frac{1}{5}]$.

Comment: Why couldn't the lower limit of integration be -2? I understand how the upper limit is 1/5, but why does the bottom change? The lower limit of integration was already -2, wasn't it?

Comment: Regardless of your choice of $x$, the bottom limit of integration will always be $2$ for your function $h(x)$. However, your function is integratable between $-2$ and $3$ so your upper limit of integration needs to be inbetween those two values. For example, $\int_{-2}^{-2}f(t)dt, \int_{-2}^{-1}f(t)dt, \int_{-2}^{0.5}f(t)dt, \int_{-2}^{3}f(t)dt$ are all valid integrals. You just need to figure out when the upper limit $5x+2$ gives you those valid values.